# Xero API Invalid Redirect URI

Tags: c#, asp.net, xero-api

The code reaches error 500 with cause being invalid redirect_uri. The code is exactly the same as the Xero documentation on github.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            XeroConfiguration xconfig = new XeroConfiguration();
            xconfig.ClientId = "sameple_client_id";
            xconfig.ClientSecret = "sample_client_secret";
            xconfig.CallbackUri = new Uri("https://api.samplelink.com"); //default for standard webapi template
            xconfig.Scope = "openid profile email offline_access files accounting.transactions accounting.contacts";

            var client = new XeroClient(xconfig);

            return Redirect(client.BuildLoginUri());
        }
```

I am trying to make a call to the xero login uri for authentication but unfortunately I am getting the invalid redirect_uri error 500. All my client id, client secret and callback uri match those of on Xero but it does not work. There is one caveat though, the new Uri creates and object of the string, in this case it became {https://api.samplelink.com} but the CallbackUri is of type Uri.

Any suggestions on how to work around this?